# Using custom data types with TAureliusDataset

Tags: delphi, types, custom-data-type

I am using TMS Aurelius with Delphi 11 Pro and having trouble with a TAureliusDataset when the underlying class contains a custom data type.

I created a Money data type that uses an integer field to hold its value.  The corresponding field in the TAureliusDataset is an integer type (TIntegerField).  When I try to post a record, I get an Invalid class typecast exception.  I used Debug to trace what was raising the exception and found it in the System.Rtti unit TRttiProperty.SetValue method.  It seems the Instance parameter is nil, which I interpreted as the system being unable to find Rtti info for the custom Money data type.

I tried registering the Money data type Rtti information using {$RTTI EXPLICIT METHODS([vcPublic]) PROPERTIES([vcPublic])} and this did not work.  Any ideas on how to resolve this?  I am open to a solution that involves properly registering RTTI for the Money data type, adjusting the field definition in the TAureliusDataset, or anything else that may help the dataset recognize the Money data type.

Here is a sample of the code (three files, the last being the form DFM code):

```
unit BusOfc.Types.Money;
{===============================================================================
  Purpose:  Data type that measures money in whole dollar amounts.

  Date:     6/6/2022

  Notes:    This data type holds only whole dollar amounts greater than zero.
            Fractional amounts are automatically rounded to the nearest whole
            amount.  Any attempt to assign a negative amount will raise an
            exception.
===============================================================================}
interface

{$M+}

{$RTTI EXPLICIT FIELDS([vcPrivate])}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  EZeroMoneyValue = Exception;
  ENegativeMoneyValue = Exception;

  Money = record
  strict private
    FValue: Integer;
    procedure SetValue(AValue: Integer);
  public
    class operator Add(a, b: Money): Money;
    class operator Subtract(a, b: Money): Money;
    class operator Equal(a, b: Money): Boolean;
    class operator NotEqual(a, b: Money): Boolean;
    class operator GreaterThan(a, b: Money): Boolean;
    class operator GreaterThanOrEqual(a, b: Money): Boolean;
    class operator LessThan(a, b: Money): Boolean;
    class operator LessThanOrEqual(a, b: Money): Boolean;
    class operator Implicit(a: Currency): Money;
    class operator Implicit(a: Double): Money;
    class operator Implicit(a: Extended): Money;
    class operator Implicit(a: Integer): Money;
    class operator Implicit(a: Single): Money;
    class operator Implicit(a: Money): Integer;
    class operator Explicit(a: Money): Integer;
    class operator Multiply(a: Single; b: Money): Money;
    class operator Multiply(a: Money; b: Single): Money;
    constructor Create(AValue: Integer);
    function ToString: string;
    property Value: Integer read FValue write SetValue;
  end;

implementation

uses
  System.Math;

{ Money }

class operator Money.Add(a, b: Money): Money;
begin
  Result.Value := a.Value + b.Value;
end;

constructor Money.Create(AValue: Integer);
begin
  FValue := AValue;
end;

class operator Money.Equal(a, b: Money): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (a.Value = b.Value);
end;

class operator Money.Explicit(a: Money): Integer;
begin
  Result := a.Value;
end;

class operator Money.GreaterThan(a, b: Money): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (a.Value > b.Value);
end;

class operator Money.GreaterThanOrEqual(a, b: Money): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (a.Value >= b.Value);
end;

class operator Money.Implicit(a: Extended): Money;
var
  LValue: Extended;
begin
  LValue := SimpleRoundTo(a, 0);
  Result.Value := Trunc(LValue);
end;

class operator Money.Implicit(a: Double): Money;
var
  LValue: Double;
begin
  LValue := SimpleRoundTo(a, 0);
  Result.Value := Trunc(LValue);
end;

class operator Money.Implicit(a: Currency): Money;
begin
  Result := SimpleRoundTo(a, 0);
end;

class operator Money.Implicit(a: Money): Integer;
begin
  Result := a.Value;
end;

class operator Money.Implicit(a: Single): Money;
var
  LValue: Single;
begin
  LValue := SimpleRoundTo(a, 0);
  Result.Value := Trunc(LValue);
end;

class operator Money.Implicit(a: Integer): Money;
begin
  Result.Value := a;
end;

class operator Money.LessThan(a, b: Money): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (a.Value < b.Value);
end;

class operator Money.LessThanOrEqual(a, b: Money): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (a.Value <= b.Value);
end;

class operator Money.Multiply(a: Money; b: Single): Money;
begin
  Result := a.Value * b;
end;

class operator Money.Multiply(a: Single; b: Money): Money;
begin
  Result := a * b.Value;
end;

class operator Money.NotEqual(a, b: Money): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (a.Value <> b.Value);
end;

procedure Money.SetValue(AValue: Integer);
begin
  if AValue = 0 then raise EZeroMoneyValue.Create('amount must be greater than zero');
  if AValue < 0 then raise ENegativeMoneyValue.Create('amount cannot be negative');

  FValue := AValue;
end;

class operator Money.Subtract(a, b: Money): Money;
begin
  Result.Value := (a.Value - b.Value);
end;

function Money.ToString: string;
begin
  Result := Format('%d', [FValue]);
end;

end.

unit Unit7;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, BusOfc.Types.Money, System.Generics.Collections,
  Data.DB, Aurelius.Bind.BaseDataset, Aurelius.Bind.Dataset, Vcl.DBCtrls,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids;

type
  TTest = class
  private
    FName: string;
    FMoney: Money;
  public
    property Name: string read FName write FName;
    property Money: Money read FMoney write FMoney;
  end;

  TForm7 = class(TForm)
    AureliusDataset1: TAureliusDataset;
    AureliusDataset1Name: TStringField;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    AureliusDataset1Money: TIntegerField;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FList: TList<TTest>;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form7: TForm7;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm7.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FList := TObjectList<TTest>.Create;
  AureliusDataset1.SetSourceList(FList, True);
  AureliusDataset1.Open;
end;

end.

object Form7: TForm7
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form7'
  ClientHeight = 441
  ClientWidth = 624
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -12
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  TextHeight = 15
  object DBGrid1: TDBGrid
    Left = 0
    Top = 41
    Width = 624
    Height = 400
    Align = alClient
    DataSource = DataSource1
    TabOrder = 0
    TitleFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    TitleFont.Color = clWindowText
    TitleFont.Height = -12
    TitleFont.Name = 'Segoe UI'
    TitleFont.Style = []
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 624
    Height = 41
    Align = alTop
    Caption = 'Panel1'
    TabOrder = 1
    ExplicitLeft = 232
    ExplicitTop = 224
    ExplicitWidth = 185
    object DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator
      Left = -24
      Top = 8
      Width = 240
      Height = 25
      DataSource = DataSource1
      TabOrder = 0
    end
  end
  object AureliusDataset1: TAureliusDataset
    FieldDefs = <>
    Left = 304
    Top = 224
    object AureliusDataset1Name: TStringField
      FieldName = 'Name'
      Size = 40
    end
    object AureliusDataset1Money: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'Money'
    end
  end
  object DataSource1: TDataSource
    DataSet = AureliusDataset1
    Left = 160
    Top = 216
  end
end
```

Comment: What did TMS say about this?

Comment: I just sent them a similar message.  I haven't heard back from them yet.

Comment: I've narrowed down the source of the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.  The exception is raised in the System.Rtti.TValue Cast method.  The TValue structure has a field called FValueDate.  It should be nil, but it is casting the Money value as a Pointer.  This is what causes the Invalid Class typecast exception.  This does not happen with Aurelius Nullable<T> values, which is also a custom datatype.  I don't see anything significantly different in their unit from mine.  Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: BTW, I updated the code to reflect {$RTTI EXPLICIT FIELDS([vcPrivate])}.  This is the only thing significant I found in the Aurelius.Types.Nullable unit that was different from my unit.